# SQL Server UPDATE/SELECT key order

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

We have a table with a key field, and another table which contains the current value of that key sequence, ie, to insert a new record you need to:

```
UPDATE seq SET key = key + 1
SELECT key FROM seq
INSERT INTO table (id...) VALUES (@key...)
```

Today I have been investigating collisions, and have found that without using transactions the above code run in parallel induces collisions, however, swapping the `UPDATE` and `SELECT` lines does not induce collisions, ie:

```
SELECT key + 1 FROM seq
UPDATE seq SET key = key + 1
INSERT INTO table (id...) VALUES (@key...)
```

Can anyone explain why? (I am not interested in better ways to do this, I am going to use transactions, and I cannot change the database design, I am just interested in why we observed what we did.)

I am running the two lines of SQL as a single string using C#'s `SqlConnection`, `SqlCommand` and `SqlDataAdapter`.

Comment: Why aren't you using Auto_Increment?  SQL Sever keeps that in a buffer so there are no conflicts.

Comment: Where is `@key` being assigned a value?

Comment: @BrianHoover as I said in the question, I cannot change the database design.

Comment: @BZN_DBer it's not the actual code that I am using, just a representation.

Comment: I understand that, but you are asking about details of a collision, I think in this case the exact implementation is important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, your queries do not entirely make sense. Here's what I presume you are actually doing:

```
UPDATE seq SET key = key + 1
SELECT @key = key FROM seq
INSERT INTO table (id...) VALUES (@key...)
```

and

```
SELECT @key = key + 1 FROM seq
UPDATE seq SET key = @key
INSERT INTO table (id...) VALUES (@key...)
```

You're experiencing concurrency issues tied to the Transaction Isolation Level.

Transaction Isolation Levels represent a compromise between the need for concurrency (i.e. performance) and the need for data quality (i.e. accuracy).

By default, SQL uses a Read Committed isolation level, which means you can't get "dirty" reads (reads of data that has been modified by another transaction that but not yet committed to the table). It does *not*, however, mean that you are immune from other types of concurrency issues.

In your case, the issue you are having is called a *non-repeatable read.*

In your first example, the first line is reading the key value, then updating it. (In order for the UPDATE to set the column to key+1 it must first read the value of key). Then the second line's SELECT is reading the key value again. In a Read Committed or Read Uncommitted isolation level, it is possible that another transaction meanwhile completes an update to the key field, meaning that line 2 will read it as key+2 instead of the expected key+1.

Now, with your second example, once the key value has been read and modified and placed in the @key variable, it is not being read again. This prevents the non-repeatable read issue, but you're still not totally immune from concurrency problems.  What can happen in this scenario is a *lost update*, in which two or more transactions end up trying to update key to the same value, and subsequently inserting duplicate keys to the table.

To be absolutely certain of having no concurrency problems with this structure as designed, you will need to use locking hints to ensure that all reads and updates to key are serializable (i.e. not concurrent). This will have horrendous performance, but "WITH UPDLOCK,HOLDLOCK" will get you there.

Your best solution, if you cannot change the database design, is to find someone who can. As Brian Hoover indicated, an auto-incrementing IDENTITY column is the way to do this with superb performance. The way you're doing it now reduces SQL's V-8 engine to one that is only allowed to fire on one cylinder.

Comment: Thank you. If you do an INSERT and then SELECT @@IDENTITY you always get the correct value back? There are no race conditions there?

Comment: Yes and no. There are actually 3 ways of getting the identity value - IDENT_CURRENT, @@IDENTITY, and SCOPE_IDENTITY - and each is appropriate in different situations. It's not a matter of race conditions, but of scope. I recommend studying Microsoft's sample code comparing the three: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175098.aspx